# Codeigniter not rerouting on live page, but works locally

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I just got some problems after restructuring some files in my Codeigniter project. Before the restructuring everything worked, but it was very messy. Now everything works when I run it locally, the frontend is build in vue (and served via npm run) and backend is built with codeigniter and is running on a php-apache docker container. However, when deploying to the live site it is not working anymore.

The frontend is built and deployed in a folder called app, in the same directory as the the htaccess-file.

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Stations/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Applications/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Auth/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Presets/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Users/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Database/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Data/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Logs/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Isochrones/* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|img|png|gif|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !version/*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|img|png|gif|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]
```

The first bunch of RewriteConditions should go to controllers with the same name, this is working fine. However, the last ReWriteRule, that should reroute all other requests to the app directory does not seem to be working, as I get a 404 error from CodeIgniter. I have an index.html file in the app directory, which can be accessed directly by going to xxxxxx.com/app/index.html, but the rerouting is not working at all.

I also have a hook, but from my understanding that hook should only be triggered once this rule applies: RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] ?

CodeIgniter v3.1.9
Php v8

Thank you for your help. Let me know if you need any other information in order to help me.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what URLs you are requesting and what you are expecting to happen... what you have posted doesn't seem to make much sense? "the last ReWriteRule, that should reroute all other requests to the app directory does not seem to be working" - Since the `.htaccess` file is in the `app` directory, the last rule has nothing to do, since you are already in the `app` directory? However, the first rule has likely already rewritten the request to the root, so the last rule is not processed anyway?

Comment: The logic of the first rule does not look right. Since you are `OR`ing a negated condition it is probably rewriting more than you expect? (You probably shouldn't have the `OR` flag on the _condition_ before the negated _condition_, since this possibly renders the preceding _conditions_ superfluous - depending on the nature of the request.) Note that the 2nd arg to the `RewriteCond` directive is a regex, not a "wildcard" pattern. The _regex_ `Stations/*` is probably not matching what you think it's matching. These regex should also be anchored.

Comment: *The first bunch of RewriteConditions should go to controllers with the same name, this is working fine. However, the last ReWriteRule, that should reroute all other requests to the app directory does not seem to be working* why not setting up comprehensive routes in C!3.x [URI-routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)?